# Server-side Charting Solutions

Tags: .net, charts

I'm looking for a .NET 2 library for generating charts.

- .NET 2
- small footprint
- fast
- basic-medium charting abilities
- pie chart support
- stream output required
- file output optional

What can you recommend? Why?

Thanks

Comment: Why limit yourself to .NET 2.0?

Comment: There are certain environmental restrictions. Of course .NET 3.5 has the Microsoft charting, but simply not an option. I wouldn't have asked otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [Microsoft's charting controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en)? It's officially 3.5 but so far I haven't run in to any problems using them in my 2.0 projects.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) with certain success in my WinForms application. It's free, lightweight and easy to use.

You can get started with the [Pie Chart sample](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Pie_Chart_Demo)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out ScottGu's post on [New ASP.NET Charting Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx).

[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/chart/step2.png))</sub>